# Implement a parallel batch processing queue in Neo4J Cypher

Tags: neo4j, parallel-processing, cypher, message-queue

When I worked with Informix SQL it was possible to use transaction isolation of simple updates to create a processing queue with something like this:

```
UPDATE Queue
SET processed_by = ?
WHERE processed_by IS NULL
ORDER BY inserted_at
LIMIT 3
```

this marks a batch of at most 3 items (queue may be empty) to be processed by the processor in the first param (`?`, e.g. server name and thread number). After this `UPDATE` finished on each parallel processor (separate threads or machines), the queue was sharded:

```
+-----+------------------+---------------+
| _id |   inserted_at    | processed_by  |
+-----+------------------+---------------+
|   1 | 2017-03-07 01:15 | host2:thread3 |
|   2 | 2017-03-07 01:16 | host2:thread3 |
|   3 | 2017-03-07 01:17 | host2:thread3 |
|   4 | 2017-03-07 01:18 | host1:thread1 |
|   5 | 2017-03-07 01:19 | host1:thread1 |
|   6 | 2017-03-07 01:20 | host1:thread1 |
|   7 | 2017-03-07 01:21 | NULL          |
+-----+------------------+---------------+
```

and each processor can work on its own on a batch in isolation:

```
SELECT * from Queue WHERE processed_by = ?
```

while they could be sure no-one else touches their items to process. As a side effect, if a processor died, it was easy for them to pick up where they left off.

---

I'm trying to achieve the same thing with Cypher, but I'm running into problems when parallel reads observe the same state and hence update the same items:

```
MATCH (n:Queue)
WHERE NOT exists(n.processed_by)
SET n.processed_by = $processor
RETURN n
LIMIT 3
```

Building on this I was able to [lock items](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-isolation.html) and do the processing with this:

```
MATCH (n:Queue)
SET n._LOCK_ = true
WITH n
WHERE NOT exists(n.processed_by)
SET n.processed_by = $processor
REMOVE n._LOCK_
RETURN n
LIMIT 3
```

The problem is that the the `_LOCK_` is applied to all Queue nodes, not just 3 of them, which could result in a performance hit if there are many of them. It wouldn't be a problem if sometimes a processor would get back 0 locked items due to other processors locking all available items.

**What is the correct way to express this with Cypher?**
If possible, I would like to also include ordering (see `inserted_at` in SQL).
I would be also happy to make it work without a limit, so just marking a single item without conflicts.

*Note: I'm hoping this is possible without using any server-side extensions.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

The problem with your first query is that if another thread/process already has a lock on a node (by setting a node property; in this case, `processed_by`), attempting to set a write lock on the same node only *temporarily* blocks your thread/process code from proceeding. Once the other thread/process completes its processing, its write lock is released, and your code will proceed to set `processed_by` -- which overwrites what the other thread/process had previously written!

The problem with your second query, as you know, is that it locks all the `Queue` nodes, which prevents any performance improvements you could gain from using multiple threads/processes.

This may work for you:

```
MATCH (n:Queue)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(n.processed_by)
WITH n LIMIT 3
SET n._LOCK_ = true
WITH COLLECT(n) AS lockedNodes
WITH REDUCE(s = [], n IN lockedNodes |
  CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(n.processed_by) THEN s + n ELSE s END ) AS nodesToSet, lockedNodes
FOREACH(x IN nodesToSet | SET x.processed_by = $processor)
FOREACH(x IN lockedNodes | REMOVE x._LOCK_)
RETURN nodesToSet, lockedNodes;
```

This query first gets at most 3 nodes without the `processed_by` property and attempts to set a write lock on each of them (by setting their `_LOCK_` properties). This avoids locking all `Queue` nodes.

If other threads/processes already have a write lock on 1 or more of the same nodes, your thread/process will be blocked until those lock(s) are released. After your thread/process acquires all the write locks, it is possible that the `processed_by` property on some of those nodes had already been set by some other threads/processes. Therefore, this query tests the `processed_by` property a second time for existence, and only sets it if it still does not exist. The `RETURN` clause returns not only a collection of the nodes that you changed, but also a collection of the originally found and locked nodes (which can be larger than the collection of nodes that you changed).

Comment: You may want to use `WITH DISTINCT 1 AS ignored`, since the cardinality of the previous match will otherwise remain the same. Best to get that to a single row.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later when I get to my computer. My only question so far (only based on reading this) is why do we need to `CREATE` Queue nodes? The Queued items come from an external source inserted by something else, containing data/relationships to process. The processors shouldn't make those up, hence the `UPDATE` statement in the SQL example and no `INSERT INTO` in sight. Note: to emphasise, my first Cypher example (with `SET`) seemed to work on a big source, if there were no two queries running at once, but I can't guarantee that. (notify: @InverseFalcon)

Comment: I have completely changed my answer, as I did not understand your question initially. I have not tested the new answer, but it seems reasonable to me :-).

Comment: Awesome! It almost worked on first try, the only thing you missed is `lockedNodes` in the 3rd `WITH`. I wonder why do we need to assume a different `$processor`? I'm guessing both of these are just because of the evolution of your answer. Well done!

Comment: If run quickly this results in 9 processed items on average, which is good enough; especially considering that there will be some gaps between these queries due to longer and random time taken to process.

Comment: I have fixed the typo (missing `lockedNodes` in 3rd `WITH`), and removed the unneeded assumption that every thread/process has a different `processor` value.

Comment: Shared my final code, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42660297/253468, please let me know if something seems off there.

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason to lock on Queue nodes is for writing the `processed_by` attribute, you might consider locking on some other node designated as a :QueueLock. Its only purpose is to be locked so you can perform your queue operations.

This of course requires all queue operations (for marking as `processed_by`, and possibly for anything that could impact that) to lock on the :QueueLock.

You'll also want to limit your nodes before your SET operation, since in your current queries, you're only limiting the return of the nodes (it's returning 3, but before that it's assigning ALL unassigned nodes to a single processor).

```
MATCH (lock:QueueLock)
SET lock._LOCK_ = true
MATCH (n:Queue)
WITH n
WHERE NOT exists(n.processed_by)
LIMIT 3
SET n.processed_by = $processor
REMOVE lock._LOCK_
RETURN n
```

However, it may help to use different labels on your nodes so operations on assigned nodes don't have to wait on the lock.

If you keep :Queue for queued, unassigned nodes (so `processed_by` will never exist while the node is in the queue), and :Assigned for assigned nodes to be processed, this should work for you:

```
MATCH (lock:QueueLock)
SET lock._LOCK_ = true
MATCH (n:Queue)
WITH n
LIMIT 3
SET n.processed_by = $processor
REMOVE n:Queue
SET n:Assigned
REMOVE lock._LOCK_
RETURN n
```

Comment: Hmm, changing the node label looks interesting. I'll see how well it could work together with Neo4J-OGM.

Comment: It looks good in theory, but I couldn't get it to work. I got an error saying "`WITH` needed between `SET` and `MATCH`", so I updated to compile and run: `MATCH (lock:QueueLock)
SET lock._LOCK_ = true
WITH lock
MATCH (n:Queue)
WITH lock, n
LIMIT 3 ...`, but the behavior was strange: each processor processed a batch, but then the first item in the original queue got re-processed. This was with the label assigning version, the first version behaved even worse.

Comment: Good catches, I missed those. I'll have to poke at it some and see what's causing that odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant of [@cybersam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/974731/cybersam)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639151/253468) I used as my final code (incl. sorting):

```
// find all of the queued items
MATCH (n:Queue)
  // that haven't been marked yet
  WHERE NOT exists(n.processed_by)
// take the first $count of those and lock them
WITH n
  ORDER BY n.something ASCENDING
  LIMIT $count
  SET n._LOCK_ = true
  // write lock will be released after RETURN "commits", but clean up sooner
  REMOVE n._LOCK_
// after locking check if they're still unmarked
// (between the first check and locking they could have been marked by others)
WITH n
  WHERE NOT exists(n.processed_by)
  // and mark these unmarked ones as ours (count(n) <= than original limit)
  SET n.processed_by = $processor, n.processing_started = timestamp()
RETURN n;
```

Based on my tests the behavior was the same, but didn't need imperative Cypher.

I believe that with some manipulation of variable names (`WITH n as x`) it is possible to also get the "locked, but not marked" nodes to be returned, but I didn't need those implementation details as the result of the query.